# HttpWebRequest received error 406 and Fiddler seems to have confused things

Tags: asp.net, curl, httpwebrequest, fiddler

I am using the following code....

```
Dim myHttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(PostingUrl), HttpWebRequest)
myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST"
myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & RSettings.access_token)
myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Version", "2")
myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json"
' myHttpWebRequest.Proxy = Nothing ' ** SEE NOTES ON THIS LINE **

Dim Byt As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DataString)
Using stream = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
    stream.Write(Byt, 0, Byt.Length)
End Using

Using myHttpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Using srRead As New StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
        ListingResponse = srRead.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
End Using
```

Where:

- `PostingUrl` is "https://reverb.com/api/listings"
- `RSettings.access_token` is (obviously) my access token for this API
- `DataString` is a JSON string posting the data to the Reverb API

If I run my code from Visual Studio (localhost) it returns

> The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable.

Trying to figure out why, I opened Fiddler hoping I could inspect content types and figure out the problem, but the response error changed to:

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

(I'm guessing from this error that I also have an issue with my Auth key, but that's a separate subject I think.)

After a bit of Googling and S/O pages I found two suggestions:

1. Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS and *uncheck* "Capture HTTPS CONNECTs"
2. Add the commented out line: `myHttpWebRequest.Proxy = Nothing`

If I make any of those changes, I get back to my **Error 406** that I get without Fiddler running.

However, if I add `myHttpWebRequest.Proxy = Nothing` line added, I can no longer see the `Tunnel to http://reverb.com:443` Log entry in Fiddler, there's no record of a request to Reverb.com so I can't inspect anything.

I'm now very confused about what I'm doing, and I guess haven't actually made any progress at all!

- I still have error 406 and don't seem to be able to inspect the headers/content type issues with Fiddler as I had hoped (please explain how if I am wrong!)
- Even if I do correct the 406, I *think* I have an authentication error.

By the way... all this is an attempt to recreate the cURL example on the Rever docs page here:

https://dev.reverb.com/docs/create-a-listing

I have also been discussing this issue here:

https://dev.reverb.com/v1.0/discuss/57bb2ca0aa8f760e004588cf

Answer (score 1):

Argh... well, my confusing over Fiddler still stands but the **406** error was caused by this:

```
myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Version", "2")
```

Should have been

```
myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Version", "2.0")
```

How simple!!